# Find other apps by name, not the package name

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to let users open apps in my app using "Open (...)"... Everything's alright on this side, I can get the app's name Parameter. But how can I find and launch apps just by their name when I just have a string app_name with the app's name value?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can resolve the application name, then you clearly have the ApplicationInfo, use this get the package and then figure out how to use the package with PackageManager to get the launch intent for that application.

Comment: May you be so kind to tell me how I can achieve that? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically using this code :

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of installed apps.
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
        if (applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString().equals("My App Name To Test Here")){
            Intent launchIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(applicationInfo.packageName);
            startActivity(launchIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but the app just lagged for around 2 secs and did nothing on WhatsApp and Spotify (that I both have installed)

Comment: @FlorentAnders It works for me without any problems (neither lags). I also tried starting "Settings" on an emulator, it works. On the emulator, I get a stacktrace in the logcat that is catched inside `applicationInf.loadLabel(pm)` (`Resource$NotFoundException`) What does you logcat says ?

Comment: I have no logcat, it just doesn't load an app.. I'll check again!

Comment: I don't need to add any permission? What OS have you tested with? I'm on M Preview 2

Comment: No, you don't need any permission. My tests were on Lollipop, not M Preview, in M, permissions will change, that's maybe due to it. PackageManager has changed a lot. I will try to take a look at that changes.